# Fluent NHibernate HasMany in Component

Tags: fluent-nhibernate, dictionary

Below is a class model and an Oracle schema that I would like to map it to using Fluent NHibernate.

```
public enum EnumA { Type1, Type2, Type3 };
public class ClassB
{
    public virtual string Property1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<EnumA, IList<ClassB>> MyDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

TableA (NUMBER(38) ID PK, VARCHAR2(255) Name)
TableB (NUMBER(38) ID PK FK, NUMBER(38) Type PK, VARCHAR(255) Prop1, VARCHAR(255) Prop2)

How should I define the Fluent NHibernate mapping class?
I don't mind introducing a new domain class if necessary. I have tried the following:

```
public class ClassB
{
    public virtual string Property1 { get; set; }
    public virtual string Property2 { get; set; }
}

public class classC
{
    public virtual EnumA EnumA { get; set; }
    IList<ClassB> ClassBList { get; set; }
}

public class ClassA
{
    public virtual int ID { get; set; }
    public virtual string Name { get; set; }
    public virtual IDictionary<EnumA, classC> MyDictionary { get; set; }
}
```

with the following mapping class

```
    public ClassAMap()
    {
        WithTable("ClassA");
        Id(x => x.ID);
        Map(x => x.Name);

        HasMany(x => x.MyDictionary).AsMap<EnumA>(d => d.EnumA).Component(c =>
        {
            c.HasMany(e => e.ClassBList).Component(f =>
                {
                    f.Map(x => x.Property1);
                    f.Map(x => x.Property1);
                });
        });
    }
```

However, this does not generate a valid configuration. Can anybody help?

Comment: I'm not sure this applies directly, but see my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1875466/auto-mapping-a-idictionarystring-myclass-with-fluent-nhibernate/2807566#2807566

Answer (score 0):

Class B isn't a component of A, it's a related entity with its own identity (ID, Type) so it can't logically be a component, as components don't have their own identity (PK) otherwise they would be separate entities.